# Pushing on Xamarin Navigation stack within Android code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I feel like this is a basic question but I can't find the solution after searching for a while, so here it is:

I have an app and I would like to handle NFC intents - that code is handled in Android. Once an NFC is read and parsed, I'd like to launch a new forms page with some information.

Here is how I'm attempting to launch my page in the Android code:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(RoomDetails));
intent.PutExtra("uri", uri);
this.StartActivity(intent);
```

The problem here is that RoomDetails is not a java file, obviously. I assume that's the issue, as I get a `Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type.` error.

I'd also like to keep my stack correct for back button purposes, so is there a way to push it on my navigation like I do when I start the page in the portable section of my app, like such:

```
var room = (RoomModel)e.SelectedItem;
var roomDetailsPage = new RoomDetails();
roomDetailsPage.BindingContext = room;
Navigation.PushAsync(roomDetailsPage);
```

Thanks.

Comment: In order to use `StartActivity`, the class has to be an Android `Activity` subclass. You can create an Activity - say `AndroidRoomDetails` - that loads a Xamarin Forms app (`LoadApplication`) with an app customized to use your `RoomDetails` page as the `MainPage`. The back stack should work with no changes, I think. It might be easier if you did the NFC stuff in a custom Android view (with a custom renderer) instead of a full blown activity. But you might need the activity.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I'd put together that `AndroidRoomDetails` class? I'm having a painful time finding relevant questions/answers when it comes to Xamarin.

Comment: I didn't have time to write code samples yesterday, and I'm at work now. But the basic idea is to use an activity just like your main launcher. I assume your app starts out in Xamarin Forms and moves back to a native Android activity. If you just make another activity that inherits from `FormsApplicationActivity` and use `LoadApplication` then it'll start up a Xamarin.Forms `Page`. Check out this sample for [native to forms](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms) and [forms to native](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native)